# Cocos2d Scroll for iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

It took several days trying to do this ([image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua3h3uo1pvdc4kc/Template.jpg)). And I don't find how do it.
In summary I need a scroll with snapping (like CCScrollLayer) on left, and change content panel (right) when scrolling.

I tried with CCScrollLayer, but the scroll is horizontal, and I can't resize.
I find other solutions with vertical scroll, but it is continuous scroll, and I need the same effect like CCScrollLayer (snapping).

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

I'm using the Cocos2D-iPhone framework.

Comment: Try CCScrollView. It's in v3, not sure if it's also available for v2 or whether CCScrollLayer *is* CCScrollView.

Comment: CCScrollView it's only available for cocos2dx. Not included on cocos2d-iphone-extensions